# What is the Rust equivalent of Serial.println from the Arduino C++ API?

Tags: rust, arduino, arduino-uno

A common pattern in Arduino C++ sketches is the use of `Serial.print()` or `Serial.println()` to debug problems.

What is the corresponding Rust idiom when programming for the Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One technique involves the use of `arduino_hal::default_serial!` and `ufmt::writeln!`

For setup:

```
let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);
let mut serial = arduino_hal::default_serial!(dp, pins, 115200);
```

and when you need to print

```
ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "{} bytes available", count);
```

The `uwriteln!` macro is not as powerful as `format!` or `println!` from `std`.  For instance, it does not support `{:02x}` for integers.

Comment: I think you're mistaken (or perhaps out of date?) that padding is not supported. From the [ufmt docs](https://docs.rs/ufmt/latest/ufmt/):

`padding ({:02x}) [is] supported on primitive integer types.`

Comment: Yeah, this question was asked in January, and my pull request https://github.com/japaric/ufmt/pull/35 to add hex support has since been accepted.

Comment: Hah, that explains it. 